# Python sqlite3: force to bind a parameter as string?

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm not actually experienced in Python, but wanted to use it to convert a CSV data table into a sqlite3 db, thought python would be perfect. I'm facing a problem: There is a parameter I want to bind as string, but if it "looks" like a number, it is stored to database as int, removing leading zeros... I'm trying to handle phone numbers here...

```
c.execute( "CREATE TABLE foo (a text, b text)" )

...

strA = "069-888888" # bound as string
strB = "069777777"  # bound as int, value in db is 697777777
c.execute( "INSERT INTO foo (a,b) values (?,?)", [strA, strB] )
```

Is there a way to force strB to be bound as string?

Comment: Where do you see the parameter as a number? When querying?

Comment: SQLite doesn't really care, otherwise.

Comment: Martin, I wasn't sure, so I actually looked into the database file itself, and the value is in the db without the leading 0. So it must be, that when inserting, it was bound as int...

Comment: What did you use to query and display that column?

Comment: As I said, I didn't query. I opened the db file with hex editor. There is no leading 0 anymore ...

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue in Python. I get a string back, **with** leading 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQLite handles this case just fine:

```
>>> import sqlite3
>>> conn = sqlite3.connect('/tmp/test.db')
>>> cur = conn.cursor()
>>> cur.execute('CREATE TABLE foo (a text, b text)')
>>> strA = "069-888888"
>>> strB = "069777777"
>>> cur.execute('INSERT INTO foo (a,b) values (?,?)', (strA, strB))
>>> cur.execute('select * from foo;')
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x1101c39d0>
>>> cur.fetchall()
[(u'069-888888', u'069777777')]
```

In other words: There is no problem here.

SQLite 3 operates with [type affinity](http://sqlite.org/datatype3.html) rather than fixed types, but because you declared the columns as `TEXT` even if you were to insert integer data it would still be converted to text and stored as such.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks. My code is actually a little more complicated than the example I have given; Probably my problem is a little different then...