# Update and delete, with value typed, in MySQL using Python

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I am trying to update and delete a row of a field, which row has a name same as the value typed, from a MySQL database. I am using python 2.7 and MySQLdb. Here is the part of the script:

```
Value = int(input("Type a number between 1 and 10: "))
cursor.execute("DELETE FROM test WHERE name=Value ")
Value2 = int(input("Type a number between 11 and 20: "))
cursor.execute("UPDATE test SET id='abcd' WHERE name=Value2")
```

I am actually trying to find out how to get what i typed from my keyboard into update and delete mysql code and make changes at the database using that value as the name of the row of the name field. As it is right now it gives me a SQL syntax error for 2nd and 4th line. Could you please tell me how can i solve such a problem?

I've had the same problem with inserting a value but the problem was solved with some people's help from stackoverflow. Here is the solutions to inserting, which worked great:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO test VALUES ('Number', %s)", (Value,))
cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO test VALUES ('Number', {})""".format(Value)
cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO test VALUES ('Number', %s)""" % Value)
```

I would also like to know how this %s are called. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

%s is called a bind variable. The delete can work exactly the same:

```
cursor.execute("DELETE FROM test WHERE name=%s", (Value,));
```

Comment: You'll need to surround the `%s` with `' '`, I had the same problem when I started doing SQL in python ^^

Comment: Maybe it is then best to use this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18231657/python-sqlite3-force-to-bind-a-parameter-as-string

There the ? is used as bind variable, and no ' ' are required

Answer (score 0):

%s is string substitution. It works like `print "hi %s, my name is %s" % ("Loudas", "Matthew")`

As for your mysql code, the syntax is a bit off. It should be:

```
Value = int(input("Type a number between 1 and 10: "))
cursor.execute("DELETE %s FROM test WHERE name='%s'" % Value)
Value2 = int(input("Type a number between 11 and 20: "))
cursor.execute("UPDATE test SET id='abcd' WHERE name='%s'" %s Value2)
```

You need to use `Value`and `Value2` as variables (not strings) as well as surround the  `%s` with `''`

Source: Working with this very stuff